# Executing jQuery on html pulled by js xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have one script 'script.js' set up to assign active class to an li tag based on the url.

```
window.onload = function () {
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Get current path and find target link
    var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

    // Account for home page with empty path
    if (path == '') {
        path = 'HomePage.html';
    }

    var target = $('nav a[href="' + path + '"]');
    // Add active class to target link
    target.addClass('active');
});
```

Second script called 'JavaScript.js' this adds in the html of my shared menu bar from a separate html file:

```
window.onload = function () {var xmlhttp; var oe = document.getElementById("nav");xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.open("GET", "SharedMenu.html", false);xmlhttp.send();oe.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;};
```

How do I make them work together in this format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Active Class</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<nav id="nav">
</nav>

<h1>contact</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you add both of those scripts into one file?

Comment: You are looking for 'nav' wich is not ready yet, just put your JavaScript.js before the closure of the body. Also the idea of @HarshanaSerasinghe is a good one, will post an answer for you with that solution.

Comment: I have already tried both those ways and it hasn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a single script to use.

```
$(function(){
    //Load the SharedMenu.html
    $.get("SharedMenu.html",function(html){
        //ON LOADED
        // Create the menu
        $('#nav').html(html);
        // Get current path and find target link
        var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

        // Account for home page with empty path
        if (path == '') path = 'HomePage.html';

        //add the class
        $('#nav a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
    });
});
```